# Append a <div> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "nyhederlang.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: parseXml,
error: function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}
 });
 });

 function parseXml(xml)
 {
 //print the title and the description
 $(xml).find("article").each(function()
 {
 $("#output").append("<div>");
  $("#output").append("<b>" + $(this).find("title").text() + ":</b> <br />");
  $("#output").append($(this).find("paragraphs").text());
   $("#output").append("</div>");
  });
  }
  </script>
```

I get both div and /div in the beginning of #output.

Why isn't /div placed at the end of #output?

This is what it looks like:

```
<div id="output">
<div></div>
<b>Some title text</b>
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#output").append("<div>");
```

doesn't append just `"<div>"` but a well formed (closed ) html element. That is a complete div.

The solution is to build your complete HTML and then append it :

```
var html = "<div>";
html += "<b>" + $(this).find("title").text() + ":</b> <br />";
html += $(this).find("paragraphs").text();
html += "</div>";
$("#output").append(html);
```

You could also append to the first appended div its content but, as is pointed by Ian, it's always more efficient to minimize the number of appendings.

Comment: Appending to the DOM is also time consuming so it's more efficient to do it this way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you are telling me: "build your complete HTML"

Comment: He means exactly the example he posted, you build the HTML in a string, then you append it only once at the end

Comment: As you can't append something like "</html>" because anything you add is interpreted as a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment), you must build the complete HTML as in my answer and append it in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a partial `<div>` tag.

jQuery will close the tag for your automatically when you append it, so the following append will therefore be placed after the intial `<div>`. And the final `</div>` you append will be another empty div after it.

What you should do is build up the whole string, and append it in a single `.append()` call.

```
$("#output").append("<div>
                   +"<b>" + $(this).find("title").text() + ":</b> <br />"
                   +$(this).find("paragraphs").text()
                   +"</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending each element; add it to a string then append that string. Ex:

```
var html = "";
html += "<div>"
html += "<b>" + $(this).find("title").text() + ":</b> <br />";
html += $(this).find("paragraphs").text();
html += "</div>";

$("#output").append(html);
```